# Django 1.9 form.is_valid() returns false

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to auth the username and password from django's own USER model. The POST Request works, is there any thing wrong with the forms.py?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login

def login(request):
    msg = "Login"
    if (request.method == "POST"):

        form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
        msg = "post"
        if form.is_valid():
            msg = "valid"

    context = {
        "msg":msg,
    }

    return render(request, "login.html", context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "username",
            "password"
        ]
```

Login.html

```
<div class="container">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            blablabla
        {% else %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: lightblue">
                <h1 style="color:red">{{ msg }}</h1>
                <form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %} 
                    acronym<input type="acronym" name="acronym">
                    password<input type="password" name="password">
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
                </form>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
```

Edit added the login.html file

Comment: I don't know, does it give you any errors? does it work? is this a test?

Comment: Try printing/logging `form.errors` to see why the form is invalid.

Comment: form.errors = no issues

Comment: What is `<input type="acronym"` ?

Comment: Yeah thanks @JohnGordon is should be username! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form isn't in your context, neither is it instantiated for a get request.

To start with try something like so;

```
def login(request):
    msg = "Login"
    form = LoginForm()

    if (request.method == "POST"):

        form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
        msg = "post"
        if form.is_valid():
            msg = "valid"

    context = {
        "form": form,
        "msg":msg,
    }

    return render(request, "login.html", context)
```

That way you can check `{{ form.errors }}` in your template to see what's wrong.

At the moment how do you render the form in `login.html`? Are you using a loop over fields in the form like this;

```
<form class="form" action="" method="POST">

    {% if form.non_field_errors or form.errors %}
        <div class="error-list-block">
            <p>
                Please correct the errors below - Ensure all required fields
                are completed.
            </p>
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.non_field_errors|add:form.errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.is_hidden %}
            {{ field }}
        {% else %}
```

Comment: The login.html is in the topic, atm i've just made a regular form. EDIT it works with my html code now. Thx